# Integrals are equal

Tags: integration

Suppose that $f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$. Prove that there is a number $x \in [a, b]$ such that

$$\int_a^x f(t)\,dt = \int_x^b f(t)\,dt .$$

Show by example that it is not always possible to choose $x \in (a, b)$.

Logically this makes sense. If you have $\int_0^2 2\,dt$, then that $x$ would be $1$, because the area on both sides of that $x$ would be the same? Any suggestions on how to get started here? Thanks

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 2):

The function 
$$F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt-\int_x^bf(t)dt$$
is continuous because is the sum of two continuous functions. We have 
$$F(a)=-\int_a^bf(t)dt$$ and $$F(b)=\int_a^bf(t)dt$$

Then, Bolzano's theorem guarantees a point $c\in[a,b]$ such that $F(c)=0$.

Comment: Is there any other way to prove this if the class hasn't talked about Bolzano's theorem?

Comment: Intermediate value theorem. Bolzano's theorem is just IVM when the intermediate value is $0$.

Comment: Okay and how do we know that f is continuous is we only know that f is integrable?

Comment: $f$ may not be contiuous. But $F$ must.

Answer (score 2):

Let

$$\phi(x)=\frac12\int_a^b f(t)dt-\int_a^xf(t)dt$$
then $\phi$ is continuous and

$$\phi(a)\phi(b)=-\frac14\left(\int_a^bf(t)dt\right)^2\le0$$
so by the intermediate value theorem there's $c\in[a,b]$ such that $\phi(c)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
$$\int_{-1}^1t\ dt = \int_{-1}^xt\ dt + \int_x^1t\ dt$$

Answer (score 0):

Let 
$$F(x) = \int_{a}^{x}f - \int_{x}^{b}f$$
Then because $f$ is integrable, $F$ is continuous.
We know that $F(a) = -\int_{a}^{b}f$ and $F(b) = \int_{a}^{b}f$
So if the integral does not equal to zero, $F$ changes signs on the interval and is continuous. Therefore...

If the integral equals zero, then take $x=a$. And in this case $x$ might not be in $(a,b)$, answering your second question.

Comment: If $\int_a^b f \,dx = 0$ it need not be the case that there is no $x \in (a, b)$ that satisfies the condition. For example, consider $f = \sin x$, $a = -2 \pi$, $b = 2 \pi$. Then, $x = -2 \pi, 0, 2 \pi$ all satisfy the condition. Probably it's easiest to prove the last claim with a concrete example.

Comment: That's why I wrote 'MIGHT not be in...' it's certainly not always the case, but there are examples for which it is (when $f$ is strictly increasing for example)

Comment: My point isn't that the statement is incorrect, it's that it doesn't actually answer the second question.

Comment: How do we know that F(a) and F(b) are equal to what they are?